# Jquery multiple Star rating control on a single page

Tags: asp.net, jquery

i have to implement star rating control for multiple div on a single page. There is a image inside every div and user can rate every image according to his/her choice, also need to show previous total rating of every image. I found many jquery star rating controls over google but non of these are fulfill my conditions. Number of div on page is not fix (its an infinite grid layout structure where user scroll and new data append in most parent div via ajax request). I need a control which works through jquery on 'n' number of items independently.

Please suggest me best plugin and logic for this.

Please remember i working with asp.net 4.0 + jquery + Ajax and interact with sql server for fetching data.

Answer (score 0):

can you please try this plugin http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/

you can see that they have used the rating in multiple occasions, incase if your page is dynamic i would suggest you to follow a naming standard for your rating by an incremental variable and assign that as a name for the radio button in the above plugin

hope it helps

Comment: Yeah i saw this plugin, but in this case we need to reinitialize radio buttons which will come in 2nd ajax request. and also it downs performance if we initialize all controls at load time. because it is an ajax based application its not easy for us.

Comment: there will not be any performance issue, it depends on how you code, if write it in a single thread you will face the issue, but whereas if you use setTimeout and update the ratings you will not encounter any perf issue. also write the code of what have you tried so far